Unable to send data to the web server. "Not found: /api/posts", 404
I'm new to Django REST framework and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.
I'm trying to develop a desktop app and a forum website, where the desktop app would be able to send data to the forum website, resulting in creation of new posts/threads. Currently, when I try to send data with the desktop app to the website, I get the following message in my cmd:
"POST /api/posts HTTP/1.1" 404 4155
Not Found: /api/posts
I have this in my urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import ThreadListView, ThreadDetailView, CreateThreadView, CreatePostView, PostViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'posts', PostViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ThreadListView.as_view(), name='thread_list'),
    path('thread/<int:pk>/', ThreadDetailView.as_view(), name='thread_detail'),
    path('thread/create/', CreateThreadView.as_view(), name='create_thread'),
    path('thread/<int:pk>/post/', CreatePostView.as_view(), name='create_post'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]

# include the urls generated by the router
urlpatterns += router.urls

serializers.py:
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

views.py:
class CreatePostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['content']

    def form_valid(self, form):

        # Get the thread object base on the url parameter 'pk'
        thread = Thread.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

        # Set the thread for the post
        form.instance.thread = thread

        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        # Save the post
        form.instance.save()

        # update the latest post date field in the thread model
        thread.latest_post_date = form.instance.created_at
        thread.save()

        # increase the user's post count by 1
        self.request.user.post_count += 1
        self.request.user.save()

        #form.instance.thread_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('thread_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
    

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

For the desktop app, I have api.py:
import requests

def send_data_to_server(data):
    # Define the url of the api endpoint
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts"

    # Send the HTTP POST request with the data
    """
    requests.post() is a function provided by the requests library in Python. 
    It is used to send an HTTP POST request to the specified URL.
    """
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print("Dataset successfully!")
    else:
        print("Failed to send data. Status code:", response.status_code)

And inside main.py, I have 'send' button which is connected to send_data method:
def send_data(self):
        # example data to send (replace with the actual data later)
        data = {
            "content": "This is the data to send",
            "thread": 1,
            "author": 1,
            }
        send_data_to_server(data)

So when I try to click on the 'Send' (send_data) button, I get response from the website:
Not Found: /api/posts
[19/Apr/2024 23:29:01] "POST /api/posts HTTP/1.1" 404 4155
And from the api.py:
Failed to send data. Status code: 404
Oh, and this is the Post model I have:
class Post(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)

Where did I go wrong?
My guess is that the error is somewhere in the urls.py, but I feel completely lost at the moment.

Did you try posts/ with a trailing slash?  Consider using SimpleRouter instead, it doesn't generate the unwanted 'format' routes.  DefaultRouter is a really misleading name: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter

Trying posts/ didn't help, but it got me on the right track! The issue was simple, in urls.py I had router.register(r'/posts', PostViewSet), while in the desktop app I had url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/". Changing the url inside the urls.py to router.register(r'api/posts', PostViewSet) solved the issue. Thanks @Andrew!

Great.  I just assumed you include()-ing the urls.py under the api/ route elsewhere.  Sorry about that!
